# How to bring a loan fund from India to Finland?

Tags: india, non-resident, home-loan

I am NRI, availed  secured loan (Against house property) in India and now I want to get that money transferred to Finland.

What is the way out to bring that money to Finland so that no taxes will be attracted?

Please suggest me in this regards...

Answer (score 2):

Best consult a CA as you may anyway need his/her service.

> I am NRI, availed secured loan (Against house property) in India and now I want to get that money transferred to Finland.

Loans by NRI taken in India cannot be transferred outside of India. Refer [FOREIGN EXCHANGE MANAGEMENT (BORROWING AND LENDING IN RUPEES) REGULATIONS](http://www.incometaxindia.gov.in/Documents/Provisions%20for%20NR/provision-for-non-resident-fema-borrowing-and-lending-in-rupees-regulations-2000.htm)

> > Loans in Rupees to non-residents 1[***].
> >     7. Subject to the directions issued by the Reserve Bank from time to time in this regard, an authorised dealer in India may grant loan to a
> >     non-resident Indian,
>
> (B) against the security of immovable property (other than
>   agricultural or plantation property or farm house), held by him in
>   accordance with the Foreign Exchange Management (Acquisition and
>   Transfer of Immovable Property in India) Regulations, 2000 :
>   ......
>   Provided that-
>   (d) the loan amount shall not be remitted outside India;

Alternative:
Sell the property in India, transfer the proceeds to NRO account. Repatriate the funds outside India as per Liberalized Remittance Scheme. Form 15CA/CB with CA certificate will be required.